# findViewById other layout

Tags: android, findviewbyid

I have 2 xml, the name is formOne.xml and formTwo.xml

formOne.xml look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  </LinearLayout>
```

and fomTwo.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/btSave" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

and i have two activity, the name is FormOne.java and FormTwo.java

FormOne.java :

```
public class FormOne extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formOne);
            EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
}
```

}

and FormTwo.java :

```
public class FormTwo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formTwo);

    EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

    Button btSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
    btSimpan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (etName.getText().length() != 0) {
                Toast.makeText(FormTwo.this, "Name is : "+etName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(FormTwo.this, "Input the name please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

i want to catch value from editTextName, and value can show in FormTwo.java with Toast.

but myapplication force close,
how i can to get value editTextName, without passing data with bundle. because in FormOne.java not any button to send value editTextName.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So how can you open FormTwo activity?

Comment: i make TabActivity, with 2 tab. first tab is FormOne.java and second tab is FormTwo.java

Comment: Then variable etName Form2 Activity from where ?
not any variable reference etName in Form2.

Comment: Please see my answer and if it is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save `edittext` value into `sharedpreferences` on `ontextchangelistener()` event of edittext and get data from `sharedpreferences` into form2 activity.

Comment: i write etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);  in formOne.java file after setContent, but keep for close

Comment: @insomniart Update your Question with last code and error logcat.

Comment: the last code, Was edited,
and log cat like this


threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: i'm sorry,

can you give me example on your answer 

because i'm not yet to make sharedpreferences.

Comment: @insomniart Send me your demo application on my mail id, after changes i will resend it.

Answer (score 0):

The first activity must start the second one passing the `String` object as a parameter. Otherwise, how can you ensure that the first activity was really started and the user typed something in the text field?

If you really don't want to start the second activity on demand, your only option is using a separate repository, like a SQLiteDatabase, shared preferences, a file or something stored on the internet, and make the second one pick a value *asynchronously* from that repository, eventually supplying a default value to accounting for the case when the user didn't explicitely saved anything.

Obviously, the first actvity would have to write into this repository when asked to. But this design may look cumbersome to me (ie passing strings via a persisten storage read/write)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get refrence of edit text which is there in the first actvity in second activity. So it may be throwing null pointer exception and getting crashed. You can't reference of the edit text in the first activity in the second activity. You will get reference of views which you are setting using setcontentview() for that activity.

Answer (score 0):

first your application will crash because you did not add The EditText in your xml for the second activity and you Declare it at the onCreate() method for the second activity.

Second if you want to retrieve strings between your activities without using intent.putExtra(""); method you can do as followed:

1-you can create standalone class like this:

```
public class Myclass{
    private String myString;
    public void setString(String str){
    myString=str;
    }
    public String getString(){
    return myString;
    }
}
```

2- and in your Activity1 you can assign value to that string by

```
String myString="What ever the string you have"
MyClass.setString(myString);
```

3-and you can call that string in any place you want by this:

```
String myString=MyClass.getString():
```